# ag-grid filter buttons not rendered in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in plain javascript and trying to use filters. Since on official page they say they support ie11 i am not able to use filter buttons in ie 11.

this is my code in grid:

```
    filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            applyMiniFilterWhileTyping: true,
            buttons: ["reset","apply"],
            closeOnApply: false,
            debounceMs: 200
        },
```

In chrome it works like charm. in IE11 i am not able to see buttons. Even html DOM element is empty

chrome:

```
<div class="ag-filter-apply-panel"><button type="button" ref="resetFilterButton" class="ag-standard-button ag-filter-apply-panel-button">Cancel</button><button type="button" ref="applyFilterButton" class="ag-standard-button ag-filter-apply-panel-button">Apply</button></div>
```

ie11:

```
<div class="ag-filter-apply-panel"></div>
```

Has anybody faced this?

Comment: I test the issue with the IE 11 browser with their official example and using your sample code. I can produce the issue in the IE 11 browser. I noticed the same issue with their official example too. Here is my test result. https://imgur.com/a/VSL31Sv It looks like some issue with their API. I get an error in the IE 11 when I try to use the filter. https://imgur.com/a/zdKp3K9 I suggest you can try to provide feedback on the ag-grid site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It is caused because ag-Grid uses es6 Set(). I needed to include compatibility shims to my application and then it start working also in IE.

e.g:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.14/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.14/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.5/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.5/es6-sham.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.